# How do I submit a form in Javascript with a delay

Tags: javascript, forms, submit, delay

I am trying to submit the form automatically with a delay in a chrome extension I am writing and it does not seem to be submitting. Below is my form and javascript:

```
function submitForm() { // submits form
    document.getElementById("ismForm").submit();
}

if (document.getElementById("ismForm")) {
    setTimeout("submitForm()", 5000); // set timout 
}


<form method="post" id="ismForm" name="ismForm" action="http://www.test.com" class=""> 
<label for="searchBox">Search </label>
<input type="text" id="searchBox" name="q" value=""> <input type="hidden" id="sayTminLength" value="3"><input type="hidden" id="coDomain" value="US"><input class="button" type="submit" id="search.x" name="search.x" value="Search" autocomplete="off"> 
</form>
```

Comment: For some reason, the code does not go into the submitForm() function. I tested this by adding an alert at the beginning of the submitForm() function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know the context, but it might be that the page has not been loaded yet completely - you might try putting

```
if (document.getElementById("ismForm")) {
    setTimeout("submitForm()", 5000); // set timout 
}
```

in body onLoad() event. As another thing, try putting as simple alert before setTimeout and at the start of submitForm() to confirm the timeout is getting fired in the first place.

Comment: For some reason, the code does not go into the submitForm() function. I tested this by adding an alert at the beginning of the submitForm() function.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what you need to do (copy and paste):

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function submitForm() { // submits form
        document.getElementById("ismForm").submit();
    }
    function btnSearchClick()
    {
        if (document.getElementById("ismForm")) {
            setTimeout("submitForm()", 5000); // set timout 
       }
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form method="post" id="ismForm" name="ismForm" action="http://www.test.com" class=""> 
    <label for="searchBox">Search </label>
    <input type="text" id="searchBox" name="q" value=""> <input type="hidden" id="sayTminLength" value="3">
    <input type="hidden" id="coDomain" value="US">
    <input class="button" onclick="btnSearchClick();" type="button" id="search.x" name="search.x" value="Search" autocomplete="off"> 
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Or, if you want to submit the form after 5 seconds, attach to the windown.onload event the call to btnSearchClick() like so: window.onload=btnSearchClick

Comment: I can't change the form. I am writing an extension for Chrome.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<form method="post" action="yourpage/" id="customForm">
    <input type="text" name="input1"/>
    <input type="text" name="input2"/>
</form> 
<button id="submit">SubmitForm</button><!-- Outside of form -->
<script>
    function submitForm() {
        document.getElementById("customForm").submit()
    }

    document.getElementById('submit').onclick = function() {
        setTimeout(submitForm, 3000); 
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is one more simple solution:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function formSubmit(){
          document.getElementById("ismForm").submit();
    }

    window.onload=function(){ 
          window.setTimeout(formSubmit, 5000);
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way that works for me:

```
 const form = $("#formId");

     form.submit(() => {

//some other functions you need to proceed before submit

     setTimeout(() => {}, 1200);
            return true;
    });
```

Now it will wait 1200 ms before submitting the form. Also, if you return false instead of true, the form won't submit.

Comment: No, it won't unless the form takes a LONG time to submit. The form closes before the timeout happens.

Answer (score 0):

Solution in jQuery (to avail of expando), easily editable to plain JavaScript:

```
$('form').eq(0).on('submit', function(e) {
    var $form = $(this);

    if ($form.data('blocked') !== true) {
        // mark the form as blocked
        $form.data('blocked', true);
        console.log('Scheduling form submit...');

        window.setTimeout(function() {
            console.log('Submitting!');
            $form.submit();
            $form.data('blocked', false);
        }, 1000);

        // disallow submit
        return false;
    }
});
```