# Automatic click Submit after 10 seconds in php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Here is i want to happened to my HTML code.. i have an html code that is written in a php code and i want to add a java script(or anything that can help me) to automatically submit my form after 10 seconds.. I am creating an examination system for my school and i want it to be time bounded.. this is the code..

```
 echo "<form action=\"PostTest1.php\" method=\"Post\">";
    echo "<tr><td>";
      echo $row['Description'] . "<br>";
      echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"Answer\" value=\"A\"> A.)" . $row['Ans1'];
      echo "<br>";
      echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"Answer\" value=\"B\"> B.)" . $row['Ans2'];
      echo "<br>";
      echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"Answer\" value=\"C\"> C.)" . $row['Ans3'];
      echo "<br>";
      echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"Answer\" value=\"D\"> D.)"  . $row['Ans4'];
      echo "<br>";
      echo "<input type=\"Submit\" value=\"Submit\" name=\"submit\">";
    echo "</td></tr>";
echo "</form>";
```

i wonder what language you can help me.. its either JS or JQ.. thankyou very much! :)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148210/how-do-i-submit-a-form-in-javascript-with-a-delay or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9947515/submit-a-form-with-jquery-after-delay or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15058562/submit-hidden-form-after-a-delay-or-immediately-if-a-link-is-clicked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using jquery [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){  // document.ready function...
   setTimeout(function(){
      $('form').submit();
    },10000);
});
</script>
```

add this inside you head tag `<head>` .. better you add id to your form and use id selector `$('#formID').submit();`

**updated**

using form id to be specific..

```
echo "<form action=\"PostTest1.php\" method=\"Post\" id='formID'>";
 .....
```

and

```
setTimeout(function(){
      $('#formID').submit();
    },10000);
```

Comment: sorry for delay... updated my answer.. check it out...using `$('form')` ..this will submit all the form present in a document.. so just to be spefific.. you can id add to you form and use id selector like i mentioned

Comment: Sir i already tried your code.. adding a `echo "<form id=\"formID\" action=\"PostTest1.php\" method=\"Post\">";` and adding a Script under my form like this-> `echo "<script> $(function(){setTimeout(function(){ $('#formID').submit(); },1000); });
</script>";` i wonder it's not auto submitting..

Comment: i tried it also in the head tag.. and it's still not working.. :(

Comment: are you getting anyerrors.. check your console... you can add an alert inside the setimeout function just to check if it is called or not

Comment: i'm not getting any errors.. it's just not auto submitting.. i already changed the time to 1000 to be 1 second but it's still not auto submitting

Comment: just asking... did u load jquery file ?? here is working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kFbLY/

Comment: I think it hits me.. Jqueries are not suitable for php files.. i dont know if im right but maybe that is the case why it is not running.. what do you think sir?

Comment: no that won't matter... you can add javascript/jquery script in your php file ....but  just need to make sure the cides is inside the `<script></script>` tag. did you try adding alert inside setTimeout... there has to be something that is breaking the code...go to chrome, press F12, and click to console tab.. refresh the page... if any error it will show there.. try it out

Comment: now its working.. and the alert is working i included in the head tag a `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` thats why the alert now is showing but the problem is.. the form is still not auto submitting.. i wonder why..

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<head>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload(function(){setTimeout( "document.forms[0].submit();", 10000 )});
...
</script>
...
</head>
```

Only just noticed your question ... sorry! The code snipped can go at any place in the file since it will only be fired 10 seconds after the page is loaded completely. I put it into the `<head>` section, probably the 'standard location' for JavaScript.

Comment: question sir.. where i will put this script?? at the head?? and what will i add to my codes after adding your code??

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
setTimeout(function() {   //calls click event after a certain time
 $('form').submit();
}, 10000);
```

It is better to change  input type from submit to button