# Multiple onClick submit() buttons and multiple forms misbehave

Tags: javascript, html, forms, ejs

I have two forms with two separate onclick submit() buttons. The problem is that only the first form gets sent off regardless to the ID`s. I tried to use getElementByClassName and Tagname as well as giving different names to the forms, but still not working..

```
<script>
        function submitForm() {
                   document.getElementById("formDelay").submit()
               }
               document.getElementById('formDelayButton').onclick = function() {
                   setTimeout(submitForm, 900);
               };
         
        function submitForm1() {
                document.getElementById("formDelay1").submit()
                  }
            document.getElementById('formDelayButton1').onclick = function() {
                      setTimeout(submitForm, 900);
                  }; 
</script>


<% if(userSecrets.length != 0){ %>
    <p>My shared secrets</p>
    <form action="/mysecrets/delete" method="POST" id="formDelay1">
      <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form" name=" secret">
          <% userSecrets.forEach(function(secret){ %>
          <option value="<%= secret %>"><%= secret %></option>
          <% }); %>
        </select>
    </form>
    <button type="submit" class="button" id="formDelayButton1">Delete Secret</button>
    <%  } %>

    <% if(userSecrets.length == [] ){ %>
    <p>You haven`t shared any of your secrets yet. <br> This is the perfect time to do so!</p>
    <%  } %>

    <form action="/mysecrets" method="POST" id="formDelay">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form" name="secret" placeholder="What's your secret?">
      </div>
    </form>

    <button type="submit" id="formDelayButton" class="button">share it
    </button>
```

Comment: You have two function `submitForm` and `submitForm1` but you use always `submitForm`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two function `submitForm` and `submitForm1` but you use always `submitForm`.

Anyway you can do that better like:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('form').forEach(form => {
  form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setTimeout(() => {
      form.submit();
    }, 3000);
  });
});
```

```html
<p>Form 1</p>
<form>
  <button type='submit'>Submit form 1</button>
</form>
<p>Form 2</p>
<form>
  <button type='submit'>Submit form 2</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I`ll have a look later on I hope it works! I appreciate your response. I know I had that typo, but regardless changing it, will carry out the same misbehaviour. I think maybe the reason is that the buttons are outside of the forms. But even they outside I don`t get how it sending off the wrong form I mean the ID`s are given so as well the action where to send it.. I wish I could understand the issue a bit more in depth. Thank you again!

Comment: _the reason is that the buttons are outside of the forms_ is that the exactly problem

Comment: Yeah I moved the buttons in the forms and it did work. Now I changed it to your code which also works. :) Obviously yours is a lot more elegant than mine solution was. I was only moved it outside of the forms as I was referring to Rus Mine comment on here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148210/how-do-i-submit-a-form-in-javascript-with-a-delay . Thank you so much for your time and effort! Appreciate it!